# PHP include statement within CDATA tag

Tags: php, include, kml, cdata

I am generating a KML file (which is XML formatted for a Google Map)
Within the infowindow section of the XML file is a CDATA tag.
So when the infowindow is opened on the map, the data within can be formatted with HTML tags. 
Here is what I need to do. I need to have a PHP include statement within this cdata section. 
I am trying to place the following within the CDATA tag, 
`<? include("http://www.yahoo.com"); ?>`
However what I see when the page loads is:
     `<![CDATA[<div>
    &lt;? include(&quot;http://www.yahoo.com&quot;); ?&gt;
    &nbsp;</div>
     ]]>`
How can I get this corrected?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file has a .kml extension, you'll need to tell your web server to use PHP to serve that file extension. Something like this would do it in Apache:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .kml
```

If it's a .php file, my suspicion is that PHP's sort tags are disabled, and that you need to use `<?php` instead of `<?`. There's nothing really special about a `CDATA` tag that'd break PHP.